# Spring MVC Testing with mixed calls through MockMvc and a Service using @WithMockUser fails - SecurityContext is cleared by MockMvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-mvc-test

I get `An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext` error when I call a `@Service` after calling a `@RestController` through MockMvc in a test method annotated with `@WithMockUser`.

Calling in the opposite order works fine as does calling the service and controller individually.  The `@Service` is clearing the `SecurityContextHolder`.  The only workaround I can think of is to set the context manually.  Am I missing something?

I need to call the service to mutate state and then test that the controller returns the correct state.

```
@Service
public class SimpleService {

    @Secured("ROLE_SIMPLE_USER")
    public void doThis(Long id) {
        System.out.println("dothis : " + id);
    }

    @Secured("ROLE_SIMPLE_USER")
    public void doThat(Long id) {
        System.out.println("dothat : " + id);
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@Secured("ROLE_SIMPLE_USER")
public class SimpleController {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleService simpleService;

    @PostMapping(value = "{id}/dothis")
    public ResponseEntity dothis(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        simpleService.doThis(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "{id}/dothat")
    public ResponseEntity dothat(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        simpleService.doThat(id);
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles({"devh2"})
public class SimpleControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private SimpleService simpleService;

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setUpLiabilities() {
        this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="simple.user", password = "******", roles = {"SIMPLE_USER"})
    public void callViaControllers() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/1/dothis").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().isOk());
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/1/dothat").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="simple.user", password = "******", roles = {"SIMPLE_USER"})
    public void callViaService() throws Exception {
        simpleService.doThis(1L);
        simpleService.doThat(1L);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="simple.user", password = "******", roles = {"SIMPLE_USER"})
    public void callViaServiceThenControllers() throws Exception {
        simpleService.doThis(1L);
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/1/dothat").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="simple.user", password = "******", roles = {"SIMPLE_USER"})
    public void callViaControllerThenService() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/1/dothis").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().isOk());
        // ***FAILS*** because SecurityContextPersistenceFilter clears the SecurityContext ???
        simpleService.doThat(1L);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username="simple.user", password = "******", roles = {"SIMPLE_USER"})
    public void callViaControllerThenServiceWithWorkaround() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(post("/api/1/dothis").with(csrf())).andExpect(status().isOk());
        setSecurityContextAndThenCallDoThat(1L, "simple.user", "******", "ROLE_SIMPLE_USER");
    }

    // Workaround - set context manually
    private void setSecurityContextAndThenCallDoThat(long id, String username, String password, String... roles) {
        try {
            final SecurityContextImpl holder = new SecurityContextImpl();
            holder.setAuthentication(new TestingAuthenticationToken(username, password, roles));
            SecurityContextHolder.setContext(holder);

            this.simpleService.doThat(id);
        } finally {
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
        }
    }
}
```